# User ID and Account ID: What do they refer to?

Tags: support, data-dump

I am doing data analysis on a data dump from Stack Overflow. The **Users.xml** file from this data shows two bits of information: **Id**= and **AccountID**=. However, it looks they refer to two different things. I show below one example from this data, where I used red to mystify the information that I currently do not need:

[image]

Since they have different attribute values, What do these two identification attribute names refer to?

Comment: In case you haven't found it: In MSE there is a post that describes the fields that are found in both SEDE and the dump: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

Comment: @rene i will keep this with my documents. thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`user_id` is the Id of the user on the specific site. For example, my user id on Stack Overflow is [189134](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy). However, my user id on [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/) is [78](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users/78/andy).

The `account_id`, is the way to link these two users on the entire Stack Exchange Network. My account id is [63984](https://stackexchange.com/users/63984/andy?tab=accounts). Using this number, you can see all of the accounts I have on the entire Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 27):

The `Id` is the user's ID on *that particular site*. The `AccountId` is their user ID for the network profile, which can be plugged into `stackexchange.com/users/{id}` and get to a user's network profile easily without having to look up that ID separately (or whatever purpose you might need to have it for).